# What happen when we use getPositionAtOffset

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I would like to know what exactly happen when we use `myTextPointer.GetPositionAtOffset(int)`.

I am  doing a search in a richTextBox using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756844/making-a-simple-search-function-making-the-cursor-jump-to-or-highlight-the-wo). I just don't understand why we need to be in a loop. I check in debug mode and most of the time when we do `searchRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset + searchText.Length)` my textPointer didn't move, and my "searchText" had a length of 1 or more.

In the loop, result is mostly empty cause `new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length)` has a range of offset 87 and 87 (example) even if `searchText.Length` is higher then 0.

```
for(TextPointer start = searchRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(offset); start != searchRange.End; start = start.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
{
    TextRange result = new TextRange(start, start.GetPositionAtOffset(searchText.Length);
    if(result.Text == searchText)
        return result;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you read explanation of accepted answer in linked question? *The reason for the for() loop in FindTextInRangeUnfortunately the range.Text strips out non-text characters, so in some cases the offset computed by IndexOf will be slightly too low*

Comment: Yeah but it's talking about the indexOf and not about the getPositionAtOffset.

Comment: My question is more like, why when we do `getPositionAtOffset()` the textpointer don't move? I don't think the indexOf is for `getPositionAtOffset()`, because I don't see why there would have an indexOf in this method.

Comment: `GetPositionAtOffset` simply helps you derive another `TextPointer` based on some offset with the current TextPointer, that's all. There is not any additional visual effect (related or not related to the caret) here.